# rxvt - how to clear scrollback

Tags: urxvt, linux-terminal, rxvt

I was hoping this would be an easy one but I don't see it in the man page and couldn't find it googling. Is there a keyboard shortcut or even a console command I can use to clear the scrolback buffer in rxvt/urxvt? Ctrl-l clears the current screen but the buffer remains.

I appreciate it.

-- Henry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `rxvt` (running bash shell) the `reset` command work correctly.

Comment: However it's very slow. Takes a few seconds for me.

Comment: This can't be used easily while a programs running.

Comment: This still takes a couple of seconds using top-of-the-line hardware. It's *way* faster to simply close the terminal and start it up again! That's unacceptable.

Answer (score 18):

If you want to clear the scroll-back by pressing Ctrl-L, add this to your `~/.Xresources`

```
URxvt.keysym.Control-l: command:\033c
```

This is like running:

```
echo -ne '\033c'
```

However it outputs the text to the terminal, without having to execute a command on the prompt.

*Prefer this since it can be used while a program runs.*

Comment: This is fantastic! Do you know if there's a specification for these commands defined anywhere? I tried googling but failed to find the name of it.

Comment: Where has this been all my life. Sigh... I really wish it was easy to find gems like this!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.